# Rails optimal query to find all articles with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm struggling to find all articles by knowing only categories users have subscribed to. Each articles can have many categories they belong to, my models look like

Article:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :article_categories
has_many :categories, through: :article_categories
```

Category:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :article_categories
has_many :articles, through: :article_categories
```

ArticleCategory:

```
class ArticleCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :category
```

article_categories table is just a storage for Article Categories with two columns: article_id && category_id

So how do I make proper query, hopefully with AR, if I have array of categories id's:

```
@ids = @categories.map { |c| c.id }
```

Comment: `Category.find(@categories).map(&:articles)` will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correction, this should do:

```
@articles = Article.joins(:article_categories).where(article_categories: { category_id: @ids })
```

Comment: oh god, that was fast and very simple. thanks :) will mark as answer as soon I can

Comment: Why `-` ? I didn't get that.

Comment: Nothing more than typo.

Answer (score 0):

You may have another table to keep track of user_categories (categories subscribed to by a user - user_id, category_id)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :category_users
  has_many :categories, :through => :category_users

  def articles
    Article.joins(:article_categories).where( { :category_id => category_users.pluck(:category_id) } ).distinct
  end

end
```